# Why does the order of setting JFrame properties matter?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

During a JFrame test program, I realized that I can't put this:

```
setSize(450, 300);
setResizable(false);
setVisible(true);
```

On the top of the constructor, otherwise it doesn't work as it should. However it works if I put it in the bottom like so:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

    private GameGraphics gameGraphics;

    public GameWindow() {
        super("Fellice");

        gameGraphics = new GameGraphics();
        gameGraphics.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        add(gameGraphics, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(450, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work if I put it after calling the superclass, but why? I have attempted to put these:

```
setSize(450, 300);
setResizable(false);
setVisible(true);
```

One by one on the top to see which was causing the problem, and it seems to to be a this combination:

```
setSize(450, 300);
setVisible(true);
```

That doesn't work at the top. However, in one of my other programs it works perfectly fine:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Client extends JFrame {

    private JTextField messageField;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;

    public Client(String host) {
        super("Messenger");

        setSize(300, 400);
        setVisible(true);

        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        chatWindow.setEditable(false);

        messageField = new JTextField();

        // .. actions etc.

        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(messageField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
```

*edit

Working code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

    private GameGraphics gameGraphics;

    public GameWindow() {
        super("Fellice");

        gameGraphics = new GameGraphics();
        gameGraphics.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        add(gameGraphics, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(450, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Glitched code (Screen appears blank):

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

    private GameGraphics gameGraphics;

    public GameWindow() {
        super("Fellice");

        setSize(450, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

        gameGraphics = new GameGraphics();
        gameGraphics.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        add(gameGraphics, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to answer "because swing is sensitive" but instead I'll just lurk and see if anyone has a good answer.

Comment: It matters because there are differences between how one platform or another might work.  When setting `setResizable` on some platforms (looking at you Windows), it changes the size of the window decorations, but for some reason, that change isn't made available to the API, so the viewable area which the window "thinks" it has isn't actually correct.  Besides, you should be using `setResizable` and `pack` instead of `setSize` ;).

Comment: Swing also tends to rely on you to make some decisions about when a container should be validated, presumably this is an optimization issue.  You don't want to be validating the container hierarchy each time a new component is added as this might slow things down when you are adding a lot of new components quickly...

Comment: If it is painting custom graphics, the `GameGraphics` class should override the `getPrefferedSize()` method to return a suitable size. Then after adding the component to the frame and calling `setResizable(false)`, **call `pack()`**  to ensure the frame is the minimum size needed to display the content.

Comment: I have over 15yrs experience with Java and written a Swing application in commercial use and still understand zilch about how Swing "works". In practice, using Swing boils down to randomly changing the code (albeit based on hunches) and testing, testing and more testing until it the code no longer exhibits any bugs. Then "freezing" it and stubbornly resisting any efforts by anyone to "improve" any aspect of the application.

Comment: @Atsby Wow, your experience sucks. I would say just about any UI toolkit has it's qwirks and if you fail to adhere to the expectations of the API, then you're asking for trouble (having worked with at four or five UI toolkits). And you think you're life sucks.  Talk to any UI web developer and the joys and playing with IE...

Comment: Take a small example, as if you are about to draw a scene, on to a piece of a paper. What if, without thinking, you simply take a piece of a paper (of some size) and start drawing, now as you draw, you realize that what you were expecting, won't fit on this size, but what can you do now, since you yourself took the paper of specified size. This is what happens, when you put everythingy at the start. Now first create an image of what you want to draw in your mind, then decide which size would be appropriate and then go by it, this is what happens when you put all in the end :-)

Comment: *"On the top"..."in the bottom"* I don't understand what you mean. Please show the exact contrasting code examples and clearly explain how you consider it not to be working.

Comment: Are you getting a `NullPointersException`?